# UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification observer not working after user as force quit app

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIViewController` that establishes observers for the app entering background and returning to the foreground. These all work fine.  The only issue is if the user force quits the app (by swiping up on the app in the App Switcher), then the  observers are 'killed' and then I have no way of knowing if the view controller comes back up or not.  Am I doing something wrong?  I've also tried `UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification` etc to no avail.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
    }

    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("VC: viewDidAppear")
        
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        print("VC: viewDidDisappear")
    }
    
    
    @objc func appMovedToBackground() {
        print("App moved to background!")
    }

    @objc func appMovedToForeground() {
        print("App moved to foreground!")
    }
}
```

Comment: “then I have no way of knowing if the view controller comes back up or not.” But then you get `viewDidLoad` so yes you do know.

Comment: @matt `viewDidLoad` doesn't get triggered in this scenario so that's not an option

Comment: Yes it does if the user opens the app.

Comment: @matt - yes it does.  My bad.  Turns out the debug console disconnects so that's why I couldn't work out what was going on.  Thank you

Comment: That is why you should use `os_log` and the Console application instead. See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/the-joys-of-logging/

Comment: @matt - Great.  Thank you.  Unfortunately, when you're learning, you don't know these things.  Really appreciate it.  You okay if I add your link to the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, turns out, is that when a user force quits an app, the debugger is no longer attached to the console so print statements no longer appear.  To fix this, need to reattach it - I followed these instructions: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/connecting-xcode-to-a-running-process/

Please note:  Print statements still won't appear but breakpoints do.  If you still want to be able to use `print(...)`, then turn on a breakpoint and add a log message to the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

To know that the Application is about terminate (killed) you need to use applicationWillTerminate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
// ...

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // inform controller 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  So `applicationWillTerminate` gets triggered but nothing in the displayed viewController gets triggered (e.g. `viewDidLoad`) when the viewController reappears.  What's the best way to reestablish the observers?

Comment: Based on the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate this doesn't get called when the user quits the app

Comment: What does it mean viewDidLoad is not triggered? If application is exit and reopen and UIViewController is appeared it should be. Before this - if UIViewController is not about to present, the viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear will not running. So, maybe you could explain the task that you have and in this case I can think about the solution.